# Error while starting Puma server with workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I am new to Rails and Puma, so the issue might be too silly with simple solutions, also please guide me if you think i am doing something wrong.

I am trying to start the Puma server for my rails with the worker. If i set workers to 0 with

```
puma -w0
```

the server starts perfectly but if i set worker to 1 or more it gives the following error:

```
E:\RoR_tryouts\ws_13.11.13\todo>puma -w3
[2120] *** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
[2120] *** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
[2120] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[2120] * Version 2.7.1, codename: Earl of Sandwich Partition
[2120] * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
[2120] * Environment: development
[2120] * Process workers: 3
[2120] * Phased restart available
[2120] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292

C:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.7.1/lib/puma/cluster.rb:229:in `trap': unsupported signal SIGCHLD (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.7.1/lib/puma/cluster.rb:229:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.7.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:442:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.7.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby193/bin/puma:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby193/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
```

Specifications:

- Windows 7
- Ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32] MRI Rail 4.0.0 Puma
- Version 2.7.1, codename: Earl of Sandwich Partition

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To cite from [the Puma README](https://github.com/puma/puma#platform-constraints):

> Because of various platforms not being implement certain things, the following differences occur when Puma is used on different platforms:
>
> - **JRuby, Windows**: server sockets are not seamless on restart, they must be closed and reopened. These platforms have no way to pass descriptors into a new process that is exposed to ruby
> - **JRuby, Windows**: cluster mode is not supported due to a lack of fork(2)
> - **Windows**: daemon mode is not supported due to a lack of fork(2)

As it clearly states, cluster mode (i.e. running a single puma instance with multiple workers)  and daemon mode (detaching from the shell after starting) are not supported on Windows.

You should either use a differt OS (e.g. Linux) or use Puma in single-worker mode. You could manually start multiple Puma instance on different ports and loadbalance between them though, even on Windows. You just need a frontend loadbalancer for that and it isn't as seamless as the native cluster mode builtin to Puma.

Comment: yosh, thanks for the help...,
also is there any other server that can provide concurrency..?

Comment: This won't work either by changing the OS. It is meant as "Cluster-mode won't work on Windows ***OR*** JRuby".
See also this ressource: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/374

Comment: @loybert OP doesn't use jruby but MRI 1.9.3. As such, his only issue is Windows.

Answer (score 20):

yup i had this same issue and found the solution at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server under the topic 'Workers'. If you're on windows orJRuby omit the line 
 "workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2) " in your config/puma.rb file.
it solved it for me. Read the link above for more info.

Comment: This worked and it provided the correct source and solution of the problem.

Comment: better than deleting it is replacing it with this: `workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2) unless Gem.win_platform?
`

Comment: Thank you. I did similar, as I only want this in production environment.    if Rails.env == "production"
      workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
    end