# Does puma work or Windows or not?

Tags: ruby, windows, web, puma

I've been trying for several days now, but I always come back to the two links that tell me conflicting information. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960872/windows-puma-unable-to-load-application-due-to-backports-bad-file-descriptor) link says that I just need backports to get puma to work (anything beyond simply installing, I can't seem to find either.) And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801734/error-while-starting-puma-server-with-workers) link suggests the complete opposite, that puma will not work on windows. And, yet again, [here](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/166) it looks like it does work if you do *something*. I'm not sure what to believe, or what processes to take to get puma working, if it *does* work on windows.

For anyone interested in my personal problem, if it can be solved, is that puma throws the same errors based on `SIGUSR NOT IMPLIMENTED signal based restart unavailable`. I've installed backports, but that alone doesn't fix it. What am I missing, besides this?

EDIT: Somehow I got everything but SIGUSR2 to work. I'd call that an achievement, except I'm not sure how I did it besides changing versions and reinstalling puma and backports several times.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you give a bit more context? Cause I have get puma serving the simplest of rack apps, but I don't anything about how to reproduce your error.

Comment: @Azolo It's the Heroku app that comes with the tutorial on getting started. An extremely simple rails app. I'm fairly sure that the error has to do with something I must have done with my ruby, or puma, install itself.